# Karma Unit Tests not able to run in Google Cloud Build with Puppeteer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, build-server

I am trying to run ChromeHeadless with puppeteer to run my unit tests. However I can't launch ChromeHeadless and get the following error.

```
03 07 2019 03:19:25.066:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v4.1.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
03 07 2019 03:19:25.071:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadless with concurrency unlimited
03 07 2019 03:19:25.080:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
03 07 2019 03:19:25.573:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start ChromeHeadless
/workspace/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-672088/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

03 07 2019 03:19:25.574:ERROR [launcher]: ChromeHeadless stdout: 
03 07 2019 03:19:25.574:ERROR [launcher]: ChromeHeadless stderr: /workspace/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-672088/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

In my Karma.conf.js I have::

```
    browsers : ['ChromeHeadlessCustom'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessCustom: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
      }
    },
```

cloudbuild.yaml ::

```
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm:node-10.10.0'
    id: 'Install Puppeteer'
    args: ['install',  'puppeteer']

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm:node-10.10.0'
    id: 'Test'
    args: ['run', 'test']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selected docker container, hasn't got required packages to run chrome;
You should change, to updated one;

cloud build.yaml to run headless-chrome tests (also, you should put puppeeter in dependencies in your package.json):

```
- name: 'buildkite/puppeteer'
  args: ['npm','install']
- name: 'buildkite/puppeteer'
  args: ['npm', 'run', 'test', ]
```